# opt.compute gradients() returns different from the weight difference of opt.apply gradients()

Tags: tensorflow

Could anyone explain how the opt.apply_gradient use the gradient? Sometimes I found the weight difference between before training and after training is not simply the gradient.

Comment: Which optimizer do you use? Ony `tf.GradientDescentOptimizer` makes steps proportional to the current gradients.

Comment: GradientDescentOptimizer, but I find the difference is not proportional to the current gradients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the same for `GradientDescentOptimizer` and different for other optimizers.

You can see implementation of the step in [kernels/training_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/93812423fcd5878aa2c1d0b68dc0496980c8519d/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L45)

```
struct ApplyGradientDescent<CPUDevice, T> {
  void operator()(const CPUDevice& d, typename TTypes<T>::Flat var,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstScalar lr,
                  typename TTypes<T>::ConstFlat grad) {
    var.device(d) -= grad * lr();
  }
```